# "There was an error parsing the body" error on requesting endpoint in FastAPI

Tags: python, json, postman, fastapi

I have implemented a endpoint in FastAPI and I am testing it from Postman. But whenever I send request I get this error "There was an error parsing the body", while searching for the error I found a solution somewhere that I need to have python-multipart installed, this package is already installed but I am still facing this error.
Following is my code:

```
@router.put('/user')
def update_user(user_data: dict):
    from crain.uma import update_user
    user_id = user_data['id']
    update_user(user_id, user_data)
    return {"message": "DONE"}
```

The endpoint except a dict like this:

```
user_data =    {
      "username":"admin",
      "id":"2d06aa3b-c25a-4499-948a-86341ac4adc5",
      "email":null,
      "firstName":"admin",
      "lastName":"admin",
      "createdTimestamp":1638268009973
   },
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have updated the question, I hope its helpful for you now.

Comment: {"username":"usama","id":"997849e8-28be-4238-a0e5-f6d71d71fde2","email":"usama.hameed@zeropoint.hr","firstName":"Usama1","lastName":"Hameed","createdTimestamp":1640242211252}
This is complete value which is send in postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in postman switch to `raw` data (currently you are in `form-data`).
then insert your desired payload:

```json
{
      "username":"admin",
      "id":"2d06aa3b-c25a-4499-948a-86341ac4adc5",
      "email":null,
      "firstName":"admin",
      "lastName":"admin",
      "createdTimestamp":1638268009973
}
```

and fire the request.

BTW, when you say

> The endpoint except a dict like this:

```
user_data = {  
      "username":"admin",  
      "id":"2d06aa3b-c25a-4499-948a-86341ac4adc5",  
      "email":null,  
      "firstName":"admin",  
      "lastName":"admin",  
      "createdTimestamp":1638268009973
},
```

you actually mean the endpoint expect only the dictionary part, because `user_data` is simply a variable name in your python code, completely unrelated to any request configuration.
the reason i specify it is because you wrote it as a `key` you the postman's request `form-data` (the picture you uploaded)

Answer (score 3):

In short, your endpoint expects `JSON` data, but your client sends `form-data` instead. Thus, **when sending the request through Postman**, you should go to `Body`, then choose `raw`, and finally, select `JSON` from the dropdown list, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489056/17865804).

Additioanlly, I would highly sugget to use Pydantic models for sending JSON data, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/). Thus, you can make use of the data validation that Pydantic offers. You can even use `EmailStr` type for validating email inputs (requires [email-validator](https://github.com/JoshData/python-email-validator) to be installed, as described in the [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/)). Example below:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, EmailStr
from datetime import datetime
class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    id: str
    email: EmailStr = None
    firstName: str
    lastName: str
    createdTimestamp: datetime
    
@app.put('/user')
def update_user(user_data: User):
    from crain.uma import update_user
    user_data = user_data.dict()
    user_id = user_data['id']
    update_user(user_id, user_data)
    return {"message": "DONE"}
```

JSON payload should look like:

```
{
    "username":"admin",
    "id":"2d06aa3b-c25a-4499-948a-86341ac4adc5",
    "email":null,
    "firstName":"admin",
    "lastName":"admin",
    "createdTimestamp":1638268009973
}
```