# Value is not a valid dict when posting JSON data through Postman to FastAPI backend

Tags: python, json, postman, fastapi

```py
@app.post("/posts")
def post_req(payload: dict = Body(...)):
    print(payload)
    return {"Message": "Posted!!!"}
```

I am using the above path operation function to receive POST requests, but when I am trying to make a request using Postman, it says `value is not a valid dict`.

In Postman I am sending the below in the request body:

```json
{
    "title" : "This is title"
}
```

The response I get in Postman is as follows:

```json
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
            "type": "type_error.dict"
        }
    ]
}
```

VS Code terminal (server side) is showing this:

```
127.0.0.1:51397 - "POST /posts HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post JSON data from JavaScript frontend to FastAPI backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759718/how-to-post-json-data-from-javascript-frontend-to-fastapi-backend)

Comment: I went through it and the Option 2 is working for me when I am using str instead of dict could you please tell me why dict is showing me an error.

Comment: Please make sure you are posting the request in the right way through Postman. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065165/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489056/17865804). When using `payload: dict = Body(...)`, FastAPI will expect a body like:`{"some key": "some value"}`.

Comment: Got it through these answers thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining your `payload` [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/) parameter like this:

```py
payload: dict = Body(...)
```

and is the **only** `Body` parameter defined in your endpoint, FastAPI will expect a `body` like:

```
{
  "some key": "some value"
}
```

Since you have a single `Body` parameter, you could also use the [special `Body` parameter `embed`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter):

```py
payload: dict = Body(..., embed=True)
```

in which case,  FastAPI would expect a `body` like:

```py
{
  "payload": {"some key": "some value"}
}
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774077/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) for more details.

### When sending the request through Postman

Also, the `422 Unprocessable Entity` error shows that the `body` received doesn't match the expected format. Hence, please make sure you are posting the request `body` through Postman in the right way. That is, go to **`Body`** -> **`raw`**, and select **`JSON`** from the dropdown list to indicate the format of your data. Please take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065165/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489056/17865804) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
{
    "payload": {"title": "This is title"}
}
```

Comment: This too not working.

Answer (score 1):

Select data type that you are sending as json in postman.
This will 100% resolve your error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).