# FastAPI JSON List in body raises 'There was an error parsing the body' exception

Tags: python, json, fastapi

Using the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#list-fields-with-type-parameter), I'm attempting to send a `POST` request to an endpoint that takes a JSON object with a `list` as input:

```json
{
   "urls":[
      "https://www.website.com/",
      "https://www.anotherwebsite.com"
   ]
}
```

Simplified reproducible example app code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/checkUrls")
def checkUrls(urls: list[str]):
    return urls


#alternatively (given that I expect each url to be unique)
@app.post("/checkUrlsSet")
def checkUrlsSet(urls: set[str]):
    return urls
```

When I test the endpoint using the Python requests library like this:

```py
import requests

rListTest = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkUrls", json = {"urls" : ["https://www.website.com/", "https://www.anotherwebsite.com"]})

print(rListTest.status_code)
print(rListTest.json())

rSetTest = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkUrlsSet", json = {"urls" : ["https://www.website.com/", "https://www.anotherwebsite.com"]})

print(rSetTest.status_code)
print(rSetTest.json())
```

in both cases, I get the a 400 status code error and the response is:

```
{'detail': 'There was an error parsing the body'}
```

I'm using python 3.10 on a linux ubuntu 22.04 vm with an ampere ARM processor if it matters...

I've also tried the following app code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class UrlsList(BaseModel):
    urls: list[str]

class UrlsSet(BaseModel):
    urls: set[str]

@app.post("/checkUrls")
async def checkUrls(urls: UrlsList):
    return urls


@app.post("/checkUrlsSet")
async def checkUrlsSet(urls: UrlsSet):
    return urls
```

which returns a `422 Unprocessable Entity` error:

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid list', 'type': 'type_error.list'}]}

{'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid set', 'type': 'type_error.set'}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1

The reason of the error you get is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73906755/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) as well). In brief, when defining a **single** body parameter like `urls: list[str]` or `urls: list[str] = Body()`, FastAPI will expect a request body like this:

```json
[
  "string1", "string2"
]
```

You can confirm the above by using the Swagger UI autodocs at `/docs`. Hence, your Python requests client **should** look like this:

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkUrls'
data = ['https://www.website.com/', 'https://www.anotherwebsite.com']
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

### Option 2

If you wanted to have the user adding the `urls` key in the JSON string, then you would need to explicitly declare your parameter with `Body()` and use the special [Body parameter `embed`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter) (as described in the linked answers provided above). Example:

```py
from fastapi import Body
    
@app.post('/checkUrls')
def checkUrls(urls: list[str] = Body(..., embed=True)):
    return urls
```

or, use a Pydantic model (just like in the last code snippet of your question, and as demonstrated in the linked answers earlier):

```py
class UrlsList(BaseModel):
    urls: list[str]

@app.post('/checkUrls')
async def checkUrls(urls: UrlsList):
    return urls
```

The API endpoint would then expect a body like this:

```json
{
   "urls":[
      "string1",
      "string2"
   ]
}
```

Hence, the client side should then look like this:

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkUrls'
data = {'urls': ['https://www.website.com/', 'https://www.anotherwebsite.com']}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, the Pydantic model is the most intuitive approach to me, any idea why I'm getting a 422 response when using both of your examples? The error message is {'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid list', 'type': 'type_error.list'}]}

Comment: Revisited this today and was able to determine that my sentry.io implementation is the cause of the problem. Still need to file the bug with sentry.