# How to get multiple dictionary (or JSON) as an input in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, fastapi

I need take this notation as an input, but I couldn't figure out that what should be my input body in fastAPI.

Here is the input structure that is entered from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "articleUuid": "1",
        "articleContent": "test post matching specific"
    },
    {
        "articleUuid": "2",
        "articleContent": "wregryujtyjyuj"
    }
]
```

In a nutshell, I  need to take each Article Content as below and need process it.

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    articleUuid: str
    articleContent: str

@app.post("/classify")
async def classification(request: Article = Body(...)):
    print(request.articleContent)
    result = response(request.articleUuid, request.articleContent)
    return result
```

I tried many bodies. Didn't work out. Could someone help me on that ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74366175/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: I'd also suggest using a different name than `request` for your variable, as that one is usually used with the `Request` type annotation.

Comment: @Chris I think you mean this: `async def classification(request: List[Article]):` yes indeed. works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

```
class Article(BaseModel):
    articleUuid: str
    articleContent: str

@app.post("/classify")
async def classification(request: List[Article]):
    ...
```

Worked for me. I found the solution after a while :)