# 422 unprocessable entity in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I am creating a web app for registration and I am getting 422 unprocessed error. This is my fastapi code:

```
app = FastAPI()

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
metadata = Base.metadata

origins = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
]

class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = Column(String(20))
    password = Column(String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)

# ServiceMaster table schema
class UsersSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    username : str
    password : str

def get_db():
    # db = SessionLocal()
    conn = engine.connect()
    try:
        yield conn
    finally:
        conn.close()


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}



@app.post("/register", response_model=List[UsersSchema])
async def register(username: str = Form(...), password: str = Form(...),conn:LegacyCursorResult=Depends(get_db)):
    print(username)
    conn.execute(print(f"insert into users values('{username}', '{password}');"))
    conn.execute(print("select * from users;"))

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=['GET'],
    allow_headers=['Content-Type','application/json']
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

I am getting the error in post request.

This is how I am making the POST request on postman:
[image: Postman request]

Comment: Can you show us how you're making the POST request?

Comment: share the request body json for the post

Comment: @larsks I have given an image please check.

Comment: @Niladri please check , I have uploaded the screenshot

Comment: @PrathamSampat select the `content-type` radio button as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `form-data` in postman and enter the value of the parameters

Comment: Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71065165/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73906755/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71489056/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the keys in the json of your body.

```
{
“username”:”parth”,
“password”:”123123”
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it is not working

Comment: Oh I see you use form input, so why use “raw” input in Postman? Set that to form as well

Comment: Also, you should have gotten a different error if you used the quotes, please make sure you share the right call with the right output. And not in pictures, but in code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to POST a JSON request body to your application. If that's the case, you should be following [this documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/), which might look like this:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class UserRequest(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str

class UserSchema(UserRequest):
    id: int

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/register", response_model=list[UserSchema])
async def register(userReq: UserRequest):
    userRes = UserSchema(id=1, **userReq.dict())
    return [userRes]
```

It's important to set the correct content type when posting requests. If we try posting your sample data to this application with an incorrect content type:

```
http localhost:8000 content-type:text/plain username=parth password=1232123
```

It will fail with an "unprocessable entity" error:

```
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
content-length: 88
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 22:47:49 GMT
server: uvicorn

{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
            "type": "type_error.dict"
        }
    ]
}
```

But if we set the correct content type (`application/json`, I'm being explicit here, but this is the default when using httpie):

```
http localhost:8000 content-type:application/json username=parth password=1232123
```

It works as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 50
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 22:49:00 GMT
server: uvicorn

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "password": "1232123",
        "username": "parth"
    }
]
```

---

In your example code, it looks like you're expecting form data. If we modify the example here the same way:

```
@app.post("/register", response_model=list[UserSchema])
async def register(username: str = Form(), password: str = Form()):
    userRes = UserSchema(id=1, username=username, password=password)
    return [userRes]
```

Then it will fail when we POST a JSON body:

```
$ http localhost:8000/register username=parth password=1232123
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
content-length: 172
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 22:54:19 GMT
server: uvicorn

{
    "detail": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

To submit data to this version of the code, we need to send form data instead:

```
$ http --form localhost:8000/register username=part password=1232123
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-length: 50
content-type: application/json
date: Thu, 09 Feb 2023 23:19:45 GMT
server: uvicorn

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "password": "1232123",
        "username": "parth"
    }
]
```

The request body in this case looks like:

```
username=parth&password=1232123
```

And requires content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Just to add this is well documented here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/